# Maximum length of a division period

Tags: fractions

So I heard someone say that if you have  $\frac{a}{b}$, then the period will not exceed $b$ digits. He said it can be proved with pigeonhole principle, but did not provide further explanation. Can someone make me understand? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far. Can you also cite the textbook, or lecture notes, that you're referring to.

Comment: You probably mean, like, the period of the repeating decimal representation of $a\div b$, right?

Comment: The best way to understand is to try it out by long division: first $k/7$ then $k/17$ (choose any $k\ne0$ of your liking).

Comment: In case you divide  a number by $7$: how many different remainders are possible?  Perform a long division.